# Mkdocs material LaTeX not rendering in instant mode

Tags: mkdocs

I am trying to use KaTeX in Mkdocs Material theme. When the 'instant mode' is off, everything works fine. However, in the [instant mode](https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/setup/setting-up-navigation/#instant-loading), only the KaTeX in the page I enter first is rendered, while the rest KaTeX (loaded when clicked on internal links) remain in plain text with the delimiters `\(` and `\)`. To render these KaTeX, I have to refresh the whole page. How can I fix this?

I tried 3 pieces of JavaScript, but all of them behaves as described above.

1.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  renderMathInElement(document.body, {
    delimiters: [
      {left: '\\[', right: '\\]', display: true},
      {left: '$$', right: '$$', display: true},
      {left: '\\(', right: '\\)', display: false},
      {left: '$', right: '$', display: false},
    ]
  });
});
```

2. 

```js
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (document.readyState == "complete") {
  renderMathInElement(document.body, {
    delimiters: [
      {left: '\\[', right: '\\]', display: true},
      {left: '$$', right: '$$', display: true},
      {left: '\\(', right: '\\)', display: false},
      {left: '$', right: '$', display: false},
    ]
  });
  }
}
```

3. 

https://facelessuser.github.io/pymdown-extensions/extensions/arithmatex/#loading-katex

Also, the Arithmatex extension is on. In `mkdocs.yml`:

```
markdown_extensions:
  - pymdownx.arithmatex:
      generic: true
```

Answer (score 1):

MathJax 3 handles this automatically and should work with Material's instant loading out-of-the-box. See https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/reference/mathjax/#arithmatex for setup instructions.

If you wish to use another typesetting library with instant loading which doesn't catch location changes, you can listen for them yourself and re-trigger typesetting by adding some additional JavaScript:

```js
app.location$.subscribe(function() {
  // instant loading finished
})
```

Comment: Well since instant mode is for faster loading, KaTeX, which is faster than MathJax, would be a better choice as far as I am concerned. I was guessing that the problem in the integration of KaTeX is when and how the rederer function is called in JavaScript.

Comment: I edited my answer above to include an example, how to achieve this with another typesetting library.